# How to correctly receive and store a local directory/path in Android preferences?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to store a local path (either internal or external storage) where the user can store some data as a preference in an Android app. I want the user to select a prefered folder in the preferences. Default folder is `context.externalMediaDirs` which returns a `File` object whos absolute path I store as string in the SharedPreferences. Later when the user saves the data the data is correctly stored via FileOutputStream to a newly created file in that folder.

Now I added an intent for OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE on the preference so the user can select a different folder. But the intent returns an URI in the format of `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/...` which I store as string, but when I try to write a file via context.contentResolver.openOutputStream() I get the error that I need MANAGE_DOCUMENTS permission. But this is only for system apps.

I found solutions how to convert an URI to a local path, but it was always noted that this is hacky and should not be done. I tried `contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(...)` but nothing changed.

So what is the correct way to receive a folder from the user, store it in the preferences, and be able to create new files there?

Edit:
current approach
preference XML (extract):

```
<Preference
    app:key="target_dir">
    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE"/>
</Preference>
```

Calling the intent

```
val targetDirPreference: Preference? = findPreference("target_dir")
targetDirPreference?.setOnPreferenceClickListener {
    startActivityForResult(it.intent, REQUEST_TARGET_FOLDER)
    true
}
```

Result handling (changed on blackapps request to not include shared preferences but only create a file)

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    if ((requestCode == REQUEST_TARGET_FOLDER ) && resultCode == RESULT_OK && intent != null) {

        //val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
        //sharedPreferences.getString("target_dir", "")?.also {
        //    with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
        //        putString("target_dir", intent.data.toString())
        //        commit()
        //    }
        val newFile = Uri.parse("${intent.dataString}%2Ftest.png")
        context?.contentResolver?.openOutputStream(newFile)
        }
    }
    else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
    }
}
```

Trying to create a new file, some time (maybe hours) after the intent

```
val targetDir = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("target_dir", null)
val targetFile = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png"
val uri = Uri.parse("$targetDir%2F$targetFile")
val stream = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)
```

The last line crashes with the permission error.

Comment: It looks like you are doing all ok using OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and taking persistable permissions. Of course you should not even try to convert an uri -your content scheme- to a path.

Comment: So post your code starting with the used intent. In onActivityResult you should take persistable permissions and immediately create a new folder or file. Once this runs ok you will store the obtained content scheme in shared preferences and create a folder or file after restarting your app.

Comment: The Intent is run maybe days or weeks before the file is created. There will be no file or folder created after the intent returns. The intent should deliver the location where I can write files for eternity. Just like defining the default downloads folder for a browser. I can never know when the next file will be created. So it's not exactly about fixing my code but I want to understand what the correct approach would be.

Comment: That i told you already. It is just for testing that i suggested to create a file or folder in onActivityResult. Once this works you can remove that code. It is just for testing purposes. You should have understood that.

Comment: When I try to create a file right after the intent returns I get an error:
```val newFile = Uri.parse("${intent.dataString}%2Ftest.png")
context?.contentResolver?.openOutputStream(newFile)```
I get the same permission error

Comment: As said before: Do not save to shared preferences now in onActivityResult. Only create a file or folder. Plese read what i asked you to do. And of course you cannot create file uris in the way you try to do it. That will not even go directly in onActivityResult.

Comment: That is exactly what I did in my comment and I got the same permission error.
In onActivityResult I take the intent, add a filename to the intents URI (which is a folder) and try to open an output stream. Results in `requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()`. No shared preferences involved.

Comment: You are not doing that in onActivityResult. Please update your code. And dont put code in comments. You still did not manage to post the code i asked for in my second comment an hour ago. You do not even have to take persistable permissions for now.

Comment: I changed the code to reflect my comment. Still the same error as I said before. And still nothing to do with my question on how this should be done, not how I am currently doing it...

Comment: Repeat: `And of course you cannot create file uris in the way you try to do it. `. That is still the case. val uri = Uri.parse("$targetDir%2F$targetFile") Your uri is invalid to begin with. You have to create the file first. And if you did you can get an uri.

Comment: Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` representing the tree. On that, call `createFile()` to get a `DocumentFile` representing the content that you wish to create. On that, call [`getUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#getUri()) to get the `Uri` to use with `openOutputStream()`.

Comment: Perfect, the comment from @CommonsWare was the missing piece, now I can store the URI as string in my shared preferences and create new files in the user-selected folder. If you post the `DocumentFile` way as answer I'll gladly accept it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a document `Uri` by simple string concatenation. Instead:

- Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` representing the tree
- On that, call `createFile()` to get a `DocumentFile` representing the content that you wish to create
- On that, [call `getUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#getUri()) to get the `Uri` to use with `openOutputStream()`

You will still need the `takePersistableUriPermissions()` call for the tree, if you wish to be able to create documents and sub-trees.

> Default folder is context.externalMediaDirs which returns a File object whos absolute path I store as string in the SharedPreferences. Later when the user saves the data the data is correctly stored via FileOutputStream to a newly created file in that folder.

If you are using the 0th index out of the array, that might hold up. Other ones represent removable storage, and if the user replaces their removable storage (e.g., swaps micro SD cards), their directory names may change. Only directories on the built-in external storage are stable.